# The method valueOf(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Tags: java, java-6, value-of, jdk1.4

I am getting an error *The method valueOf(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (int)* for the below line when I compile the code in jdk1.4(j2sdk1.4.1_05). If I compile the same code in jdk1.6.0_14, the code works fine.

`HashMap offMap = new HashMap(); 
offMap.put("price", Integer.valueOf(offer.getPrice()));`

My question is why this code is giving error when compiled in jdk1.4 and not in jdk1.6. Any suggestions to get in compiled?

Note: This is pre-written code. Need your suggestion for code change and get it compiled without errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Java 1.4, I think you want the [`Integer(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer%28int%29) constructor like

```
offMap.put("price", new Integer(offer.getPrice()));
```

[`Integer.valueOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29) wasn't available in Java 1.4 (the Javadoc says it was added in Java 1.5).

Answer (score 6):

[There was no such method in Java 4.](http://da2i.univ-lille1.fr/doc/j2sdk-1.4.2/api/java/lang/Integer.html)

[There was such a method in Java 6.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29)

Answer (score 2):

Because in later versions of Java, the Integer class has a method `valueOf(int)`.

You should try:

```
offMap.put("price", new Integer(offer.getPrice()));
```

Answer (score 1):

whatever value is in "offer.getPrice()", it shouldn't be in String and if it is so,it will show Error like you mentioned above

so you should try the below code

`offMap.put("price", Integer.parseInt(offer.getPrice().toString()));`

or

`offMap.put("price", Integer.valueOf(offer.getPrice().toString()));`